# MySQL comparison precedence / tautologies

Tags: mysql, boolean-expression

I am just playing around with MySQL and was wondering why the below statements return all rows, meaning that the WHERE clause is always true.
For simplicity I am using the public sandbox here:
http://headfirstlabs.com/sql_hands_on

```
SELECT * FROM drink_info where color = '' = '';
SELECT * FROM drink_info where color = '' = 'x';
SELECT * FROM drink_info where color = 'x' = 'x';
SELECT * FROM drink_info where color = 'x' = 'y';
SELECT * FROM drink_info where color = true = false;
SELECT * FROM drink_info where color = false = true;
```

However, the WHERE clause evaluates to false using these:

```
SELECT * FROM drink_info where color = true = true;
SELECT * FROM drink_info where color = false = false;
```

This results in an error as I'd expect:

```
SELECT * FROM drink_info where color = false := false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL evaluates expressions left-to-right, for same operators. If they are different operators of course operator precedence takes over. But when using the same operator as in your example, `a + b + c` is evaluated as if you had done `(a + b) + c`.

It's easier to see if you use numbers:

```
mysql> select 1 = 2 = 2;
+-----------+
| 1 = 2 = 2 |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+

mysql> select 1 = (2 = 2);
+-------------+
| 1 = (2 = 2) |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
```

In the first example, (1 = 2) evaluates to 0, then this result is compared to 2. They aren't equal, so the total result is false, which in MySQL is the same as 0.

But in the second example, (2 = 2) evaluates to true, or 1. Then 1 is compared to the leftmost 1, and that result is true, or 1.

For your example of `color = true = true` and `color = false = false`, both expressions will be false if `color` has a value of 0.

---

Re your comment:

> I thought everything > 0 and whatever string value equals true.

No, string values evaluated in a numeric context can be a number if the string contains leading digits, but it defaults to 0 if no digits. For example, the string `'123abc'` is the number 123, but the string `'abc'` is the number 0.

In your example, `color = 'x' = 'x'`, the first comparison is false, since I assume color is not equal to `'x'`. True and false in MySQL are exactly the integers 1 and 0 (this is not standard SQL). So the second comparison is comparing 0 to `'x'`, which puts `'x'` in a numeric expression, so it is 0. That makes the full expression `0 = 0` which is true.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
So that means in
    SELECT * FROM drink_info where color = 'x' = 'x';
The second x is evaluated to false. Is that documented somewhere? I thought everything > 0 and whatever string value equals true.